# Linking the day/date on Calendar with a table in the database (sql) using ASp.NET

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, calendar

I've been tasked to create a booking website for Employees and Vehicles. I have created tables with Sql with all the required data, now my biggest challenge is linking the tables with the calendar. What I mean is that when a day has been selected on the Calendar it should redirect me to the table that contains data about the bookings for that day. I'm still new and don't know much about this, please bear with me.

Comment: If you have a table for each day then your database design is broken. THe bookings should all be in one table and simply have a DateTime field to represent the Date/Time of the booking.

Comment: There is a booking table, made specifically for the bookings and has all those fields (Date/Time) but the question is how do you view that table from a Calendar day selection? i.e: When you click the day on the calendar, the table appears. @BenRobinson

Comment: It is difficult to answer that question with anything more specific that "by writing code that extracts the relevent data from the database and displays it to the user". You need to find a tutorial on retrieving records from a database which is not a good fit for a question on SO, try google.